# перекодировка cp866 to utf-8 С

Tags: c, utf-8

Пишу на `С`. По сети получаю данные в кодировке `cp866` с кирилицей, необходимо эти данные записать в `.xml` файл в `utf-8`, сторонние библиотеки крайне не желательно использовать. Программа должна работать на дебиан, но желательно кросплатформенно.
Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: Желательно добавить пример кода в вопрос, тогда мы быстрее сможем вам помочь.

Comment: Создайте/сгенерируйте две таблицы (по 128 элементов): в первую занесите коды символов соответствующие кодировке cp866, во вторую - коды соответствующие тем же символам, но в utf-8. И далее, простым сравнением символов текста с первой таблицей, определяете нужный индекс второй таблицы и записываете в файл соответствующий utf-8 код.

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Comment: `iconv` вам в помощь, он встроенный в libc. Там кстати есть и таблицы, если взять исходники :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В виду того что не уверен в возможностях платформы назначения, реализовал на основе предложения @zed

```
void Conv_CPToUTF8(char *utf_string, char *cp_string)
{
union
{
    unsigned short int code_utf;
    char ch_for_buff[2];
} to_utf;
for(int i=0,j=0; i<strlen(cp_string); i++,j+=2)
{
    if((unsigned char)cp_string[i]>=0x80 && (unsigned char)cp_string[i]<=0xAF)
    {
        to_utf.code_utf = 0xD010+(unsigned char)cp_string[i];
        utf_string[j]=to_utf.ch_for_buff[1];
        utf_string[j+1]=to_utf.ch_for_buff[0];
    }
    if((unsigned char)cp_string[i]>=0xE0 && (unsigned char)cp_string[i]<=0xEF)
    {
        to_utf.code_utf = 0xD0A0+(unsigned char)cp_string[i];
        utf_string[j]=to_utf.ch_for_buff[1];
        utf_string[j+1]=to_utf.ch_for_buff[0];
    }
    if((unsigned char)cp_string[i]==0xF0)
    {
        to_utf.code_utf = 0xD081;
        utf_string[j]=to_utf.ch_for_buff[1];
        utf_string[j+1]=to_utf.ch_for_buff[0];
    }
    if((unsigned char)cp_string[i]==0xF1)
    {
        to_utf.code_utf = 0xD191;
        utf_string[j]=to_utf.ch_for_buff[1];
        utf_string[j+1]=to_utf.ch_for_buff[0];
    }
    if((unsigned short int)cp_string[i]>=0x30 && (unsigned short int)cp_string[i]<=0x39)
    {
        to_utf.code_utf = (unsigned short int)cp_string[i];
        utf_string[j--]=to_utf.ch_for_buff[0];
    }
}
}
```

всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Для преобразование кодировок в *nix мире есть стандартная функция [`iconv(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/iconv).

```
#include <iconv.h>
// ...    

  char *cp866_str  = get_my_cp866str ();
  size_t str_len   = strlen (cp866_str);
  size_t u8_buf_sz = str_len * 2 + 1;
  char *u8_buf     = malloc (u8_buf_sz);
  assert (u8_buf);

  iconv_t cd = iconv_open ("UTF-8", "CP866"); // codec descriptor
  assert (!errno);
  // iconv() изменяет свои аргументы, так что желательно сделать копии
  char *cp866_str_p = cp866_str; 
  char *u8_buf_p = u8_buf;
  size_t cp866_char_left = str_len;
  size_t u8_bytes_left = ;
  size_t str_len
  size_t converted_chars = iconv (cd,
                                  &cp866_str_p, &cp866_char_left,
                                  &u8_buf_p,    &u8_bytes_left);

  assert (converted_chars != (size_t)-1);
  assert (u8_bytes_left >=1);
  *u8_buf_p = 0; // добавление терминирующего нуля
  iconv_close(cd);

  return u8_buf;
```

По поводу переносимости, POSIX гарантирует наличие оной функции, но не гарантирует, какие именно кодировки она будет поддерживать, но AFAIK на всех современных libc общего назначения есть поддержка и 866 и utf-8.

На вроде-как-POSIX-но-не-совсем платформах её может не быть в ближайшем доступе.